# No error if WPF Image Source Link doesn't exist

Tags: c#, wpf, image, hyperlink

I use this code to set a link as WPF image source:

```
bi3.BeginInit();
bi3.UriSource = new Uri("[here is a link]" + textBox2.Text + ".png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
bi3.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
bi3.EndInit();
```

How can I know if link to image does exist? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is it a remote or local image you are trying to load?

Comment: What means remote/local image? It is an image from Internet.

Comment: That would qualify as `remote` ;-) Which means you can't just simply use `File.Exists` (for local files).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private static bool UriExit(Uri uri)
{
    try
    {
        var request = WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Method = "HEAD";
        var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        return (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

call it as below

```
bool val = UriExit(bi3.UriSource);
```